# How to change make my discord bot change prefix

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I tried following a tutorial and did the exact same thing
but my bot doesn't change prefix
there are not many details to the problem
i made a prefixes.json, but when i used the command it didn't update the file

async def on_guild_join(guild):

```
with open("prefixes.json", "r") as f:

    prefix = json.load(f)   

    prefix[str(guild.id)] = "m!"

    

with open("prefixes.json", "w") as f:

    json.dump(prefix, f, indent=4)
```

@client.event

async def on_guild_remove(guild):

```
with open("prefixes.json", "r") as f:

    prefix = json.load(f)

    prefix.pop(str(guild.id))

    

with open("prefixes.json", "w") as f:

    json.dump(prefix, f, indent=4)
```

@client.event

async def setprefix(ctx, *, newprefix: str):

```
with open("prefixes.json", "r") as f:

    prefix = json.load(f)

    

    prefix[str(guild.id)] = newprefix

    

with open("prefixes.json", "w") as f:

    json.dump(prefix, f, indent=4)
```

`

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve exactly? At the moment you're just reading/writing to a file called 'prefixes.json'?

Comment: yes, well it technically reads it, but it doesn't update the file

Comment: So you just want the file updating?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your command uses the `@client.command()` decorator. `@client.event` is used for listening to discord events - you need to use `command` to add a new command.

```py
@client.command()
async def setprefix(ctx, *, newprefix: str):
    with open("prefixes.json", "r") as f:
        prefix = json.load(f)

    prefix[str(ctx.guild.id)] = newprefix

    with open("prefixes.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(prefix, f, indent=4)
```